# Make a dynamic text Select Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic

I show me the code that generates conflict :

```
$builder->add('producto', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ProyectoAdminBundle:Catalogo',
        'property' => 'articulo',
    ));
```

I use a form where you look all products of a database for dynamically loaded into the select. The problem is that when the customer submits the form, tells me that can not be converted to string object. It means that all products that brings me to the base, bring them as objects rather than text type . How do I fix the problem? Thank You

Comment: Have you defined a __toString() on the `Catalogo` entity? That at least might suggest where the object is being cast to a string. Although in general, if you define the `property` option you shouldn't need a __toString() method.

Comment: @Geronimo: Are you trying to add new `Catalogo` object in a inline manner? That is, you are doing some `JS` which dynamically appends another `<option>` tag?